# a method that converts a daynumber into a date

Tags: java, arrays, date

A number between 1 and 365 is requested from the user. The number represents the day number of the year. The corresponding date is displayed.

I get stuck on the method calculationDateWithDayNumber

An example: the number 105 should be converted to date 15 April. My result is -31 February.
Where does it go wrong?

```
public class DateOperations {
    
    private final static String[] MONTHS = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", 
            "September", "October", "November", "December"  };
    
    private static final int[] NUMBERDAYS = {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
    
    public static String calculationDateWithDayNumber(int day)
    {
        int month = 0;
        for (int i=0; day>=NUMBERDAYS[i] ;i++)  
            {day=-NUMBERDAYS[i];
            ++ month;}
             
            String nameMonth = MONTHS[month];

             
            
        String datum = String.format("%d%s",day, nameMonth);
        
        return datum;
    }

}
```

Comment: On looking initially, I think the code was meant to be `day-=NUMBERDAYS[i];` and not `day=-NUMBERDAYS[i];` ?

Comment: Do you need a certain format of the date `String`? Like `15.04.2020` or `2020-04-15`? Why are you calculating this yourself, when there's `java.time`? You could get the desired result with a lot less lines of code... In addition, could day no 105 of year 2020 be the 14th (not 15th) of April? I think this February had 29 days because 2020 is a leap year.

Comment: Using the java time package is much easier than to calculate it your self, https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_date.asp. Also java includes date formating functionality which could be used. So you could create a date at 1-1-2000 and add the number of days to get the correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are practicing.
Two fixes are needed, see below comments in code

`day=-NUMBERDAYS[i]` means you are assign value of (-1*`NUMBERDAYS[i]`) in `day`. But I think you should minus `NUMBERDAYS[i]` from `day` like `day - NUMBERDAYS[i]` and assign the value in `day` like `day = day - NUMBERDAYS[i]` or using shorthand operator like `day -= NUMBERDAYS[i]`

```
  public static String calculationDateWithDayNumber(int day) {
    int month = 0;
    for (int i = 0; day > NUMBERDAYS[i]; i++) {  // Fix here, remove equals since day can be last day of month
      day = day - NUMBERDAYS[i]; // Fix here, minus the NUMBERDAYS[i] from day
      ++month;
    }
    String nameMonth = MONTHS[month];
    String datum = String.format("%d %s", day, nameMonth);
    return datum;
  }
```

Output: `15 April`

Comment: Indeed, I'm a student. I have one more question. What's the difference between day = day - NUMBERDAYS[i]; and day = - NUMBERDAYS[i];?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this very easily with the java.time API, using [`ofYearDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#ofYearDay-int-int-). Since you said that the number can be from 1 to 365, you are probably assuming a non-leap year, so you can pass any non-leap year as the first parameter:

```
public static String getMonthDayFromDayOfYear(int dayOfYear) {
    // 2019 is a non-leap year
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.ofYearDay(2019, dayOfYear);

    // "ddMMMM" seems to be your desired format
    return DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMMM").withLocale(Locale.US).format(date);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `java.time` this task can be done without any custom calculation (which wouldn't be trivial at all).

Basically, you can just take the date of today and adjust the day of year preserving the year. Have a look at this example:

```
public static String getDateFromDayOfYear(int dayOfYear) {
    // take "today" (basically just to have the current year
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now()
                                    // and adjust the day of year using the argument
                                    .withDayOfYear(dayOfYear);
    // then return a String representation of that date in a desired format (GER/DE here)
    return localDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.uuuu"));
}
```

Using it in a `main` method like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int apr14 = 105;
    System.out.println(getDateFromDayOfYear(apr14));
}
```

would output

```
14.04.2020
```

which is obviously not your desired output because your task doesn't consider leap years
(those with 366 days due to a Februray 29th, like in 2020).

Answer (score -1):

I think you need the below code snippet :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int dayOfYear = 60;
  int year = 2019;
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
  calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, dayOfYear);
  System.out.println("Day " + dayOfYear + " of the current year = " + calendar.getTime());

}
```

You need to set the year, to take of the leap year

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).